# Identify the scrolling action reason with in the on scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, eventargs

I have use the following code snippet to display the table.

```
<div id="results" class="scrollingdatagrid" style="height: 200px;overflow: scroll;">

      <table id="mstrTable" cellspacing="0" border="1">
         <thead>
          <tr> 
            <th>File Number</th>
            <th>Date1</th>
            <th>Date2</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Num.</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr> 
            <td>KABC</td>
            <td>09/12/2002</td>
            <td>09/12/2002</td>
            <td>Submitted</td>
            <td>1</td>

          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td>KCBS</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>Lockdown</td>
            <td>2</td>
          </tr>

          <tr> 
            <td>WFLA</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>Submitted</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>WTSP</td>
                <td>09/15/2002</td>
                <td>09/15/2002</td>
                <td>In-Progress</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
            <td>KCBS</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>Lockdown</td>
            <td>2</td>
          </tr>

          <tr> 
            <td>WFLA</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>Submitted</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>WTSP</td>
                <td>09/15/2002</td>
                <td>09/15/2002</td>
                <td>In-Progress</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
            <td>KCBS</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>Lockdown</td>
            <td>2</td>
          </tr>

          <tr> 
            <td>WFLA</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>Submitted</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>WTSP</td>
                <td>09/15/2002</td>
                <td>09/15/2002</td>
                <td>In-Progress</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
            <td>KCBS</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>Lockdown</td>
            <td>2</td>
          </tr>

          <tr> 
            <td>WFLA</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>Submitted</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>WTSP</td>
                <td>09/15/2002</td>
                <td>09/15/2002</td>
                <td>In-Progress</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
            <td>KCBS</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>Lockdown</td>
            <td>2</td>
          </tr>

          <tr> 
            <td>WFLA</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>Submitted</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>WTSP</td>
                <td>09/15/2002</td>
                <td>09/15/2002</td>
                <td>In-Progress</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
            <td>KCBS</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>Lockdown</td>
            <td>2</td>
          </tr>

          <tr> 
            <td>WFLA</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>09/11/2002</td>
            <td>Submitted</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td>WTSP</td>
            <td>09/15/2002</td>
            <td>09/15/2002</td>
            <td>In-Progress</td>
            <td>4</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

In this i have press down Arrow /UpArrow scrolling action happen . How to identify the scrolling action happens due to the keyPress/ Mouse interaction with in onScroll event using onscroll event args

Comment: 24 QUESTIONS AND NOT ACCEPTED ANSWERS AT ALL!? This is not how SO works. Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) some answers.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand exactly what you're after. Here is an example of how to capture the up, down, left and right arrows and which is clicked on your page example.

**UPDATED FOR SCROLL DIRECTION**

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EqkwZ/17/)

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    var tmpCode = e.keyCode;
    switch (tmpCode) {
    case 37:
        console.log("left");
        break;
    case 38:
        console.log("up");
        break;
    case 39:
        console.log("right");
        break;
    case 40:
        console.log("down");
        break;
    default:
        console.log(tmpCode);
        break;
    }
});

$("#results").on("scroll", function (e) {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
        console.log("down scroll");
    } else {
        console.log("up scroll");
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to identify the reason for scrolling with in the on scroll event. For expample mouse wheel action , uparrow Key pressed like that . How to achieve this in onscroll event

Comment: I updated my answer to include the scroll direction, once again the arrow or key pressed will log to the console as well as the scroll direction of your DIV. Hope this is what you're after...